# combine facet_wrap and geom_segment with free x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a faceted columns plot like this:

```
ggplot(postgfc_prob, aes(x = as.character(Quarter), y = fitted, fill = as.factor(region))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_segment(data = postgfc_prob, aes(x=as.numeric(as.factor(Quarter)) - 0.5, xend=as.numeric(as.factor(Quarter)) + 0.5, yend = Threshold, y= Threshold, colour = as.factor(region)), linetype = 1, size = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Country, scale = "fixed", ncol = 4) +
  theme(strip.background =element_rect(fill="grey")) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(colour = 'black')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("chocolate1", "red")) +
  ylab("SS Probability") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

facet_wrap_sudden_stops
[image: facet_wrap_sudden_stops]

I would like exactly the same facets, but without blank columns for each country i.e. `scales="free_x"` inside the geom_segment aesthetics. The problem is that changing the code messes with the factors

example free_x
[image: example free_x]

Any suggestion? Besides, why the segment colour does not correspond to the column ones?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the main ggplot call, you use `x = as.character(Quarter)` and in the geom_segment you use `x = as.numeric(as.factor(Quarter))`. You will lose factor level information if you do `as.numeric()`, so could you try the plot without both `x = as.factor(Quarter)` and see if that improves it?

Comment: If I set them both to ```x= as.numeric(as.factor(Quarter))``` it works: I think I understood the mistake. But now it reports the factor levels for each facet, do I have to solve this issue manually or is there another way?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my part, what I meant was doing both `x` statement with `as.factor(Quarter)` without the `as.numeric()`.

Comment: In that case the geom_segment does not show up because I cannot control its length